# Read big and complex csv and insert in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

I'm reading a csv via pandas in a dataframe and want to write it to SQL Server:

```
with pd.read_csv(r"my.csv", sep=";", chunksize=4, usecols=['some', 'columns'...],encoding='cp1252') as reader:
    reader
    for chunk in reader:
        # create db con
        for index, row in chunk.iterrows():
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO myTable (some, columns ... ) VALUES (?,?...)', row['some'], row['column']...)
```

Works well with simple csv files, like shown in many examples. But with my bigger file I'm get some trouble. Especially with data types and null values.

1. Column in database is String but values in CSV can be int, float, string or null. So I do: `str(myValue)`
   works with int and float but if there is a null I get a "nan" in my database and not null. Without `str()` I get data type errors when there as number values read from csv.
2. Same with Bool values in csv represented as 0 and 1 and null as well. But a 'nan' via `bool(myBoolValue)` is converted true. without `bool()` I get a dataType error.
3. It's quite slow. with pdi (kettle) I get ~1800 rows/s to database. Here just maybe 100 rows/s.

Any idea how I could handle this?
Can I define DataType already when reading the values?

Comment: Is there any preprocessing going on in pandas before writing to the db. Just wondering I f you could just dump it straight without pandas

Comment: No, just read the required columns in chunks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a process called 'df.to_sql'.  I think this is somewhat new; I came across is a couple months ago, and I don't recall seeing this at all even 6 months ago.

```
from fast_to_sql import fast_to_sql as fts
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=your_server_name_here;"
                      "Database=your_database_name_here;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      )

# build your data frame here...

# df_final.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=True)
fts.fast_to_sql(df_final, x, conn, custom=None, if_exists="append", temp=False)
# you can push data to your DB in chunks as well
# chunksize=1000

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I have used this for passing data from hundreds of data frames to hundreds of tables in SQL Server in the past few months, and I have never encountered a single issue with data types and null values, as you described.

You can read about the df.to_sql here.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Tested it... 
If i make type(chunk) I get <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
OK so far...

But
fts.fast_to_sql(chunk, 'myTable', cnxn, custom=None, if_exists="append", temp=False)
Creates:
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('String data, right truncation: length 512 buffer 2', 'HY000')

Comment: Both worked fine for me.  Although 'fts.fast_to_sql' didn't seem much faster than 'df.to_sql'.  It was slightly faster, but hardly noticeable.

Comment: I tested df.to_sql which works quite well. Most values where inserted correctly (even null looks good). Long ints in str columns where converted to exponentials, but I got this with defined dtypes while reading the csv. 
But it is slow... I need to test a bit more. Maybe I have to come back with more dumb quetions. But for now: big THX!

Comment: Please mark my answer as useful, if it helped you out.